# How to customize read more link

Tags: posts, excerpt

Situation is I have some posts which are showing in my home page there are some read more links(excerpts) after clicking on those links they go to the complete post page, now the issue is i want to open a pdf on one of the read more link, it is not working right now  what i have done is I pasted the pdf url on the post page and thought it will open the pdf after clicking it but shows the page with the same url and not opening the pdf I know i am doing wrong what I am supposed to do.

In nutshell how can i open any file such as .doc,image,pdf on read more link (excerpts)

**I am using latest wp3.4 tweenty-eleven theme**

I am complete beginner so don't laugh over any silly mistake of mine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of ways this can be achieved, some more complex than others, some offering more functionality than others, however it all depends on your usage-case.

For now, the most simple method is to use a combination of,

- [custom fields](http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields)

  and a...
- [conditional if/else statement](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.else.php)

Step 1)

In your post edit screen you need to create a custom field. If the custom field box is not visible to you in the post edit screen then click on **screen options** at the top right of your screen and then *check* the **Custom Fields** checkbox after which the **Custom Fields** meta-box will appear on screen.

Refer to the screenshot below if necessary.

[image]

Within the **Custom Field** meta-box click **Enter New** and for the **name** (meta key) of your **value** (meta value) enter something like `read_pdf`.

Then enter the link to your PDF attachment in the adjacent **value** field.

Refer to the screenshot below if necessary.

[image]

Step 2)

Next in your theme file, the one in which controls the display of your posts, which may be your `index.php` file or your `archive.php` (or something else) you need to look for your post loop and replace the current read more link with a conditional statement.

Example;

```
 <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

        <?php the_title(); ?>

        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>

        <?php if ( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'read_pdf', true) ) : ?>

          //replace read more link to value of read_pdf key if exists

          <a href="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'pdf_key', true) ); ?>">
          read more
          </a>

        <?php else : ?>

          //show normal read more link if no pdf attached.

          <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
          read more
          </a>

        <?php endif; ?>
    
  <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

The code above is an example of how your template files may look, but I can't know for sure. However the purpose here is to illustrate how to use **Custom Fields** in their basic form to set a link to a document, then have that value replace the standard read more link when it exists via a conditional `if/else` statement.

**NOTE: Once you enter the key of "read_pdf" once, you do not have to keep on re-entering it. Instead you will be able to select it from a drop down box in the Custom Field meta-box from then onward.**

## UPDATE

After further dicussion with the OP above, the solution used for the Twenty Eleven theme is that of below, however the solution above is also applicable as a general approach for themes that do not control the output of their excerpts via the functions.php file.

In your functions.php file on line 364 (Twenty Eleven Theme v1.4) replace the function with;

```
function twentyeleven_custom_excerpt_more( $output ) {

    global $post;

    if ( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'read_pdf', true) ) {

        $output .= '<a href="'.get_post_meta($post->ID, 'read_pdf', true) .'">read more</a>';
        return $output;

        }
        else
        {
            if ( has_excerpt() && ! is_attachment() ) {
                $output .= twentyeleven_continue_reading_link();
            }
            return $output;

        }

}
add_filter( 'get_the_excerpt', 'twentyeleven_custom_excerpt_more' );
```

Comment: Function modified to now correctly show output of the excerpt as well as the read more link.