# Read more opens attachment

Tags: posts, custom-field, excerpt, read-more

I'd like the read more button to open the file attached to the post, if there is an attachment. I found [this post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/56048/how-to-customize-read-more-link) which I think does what I want, and I've done step 1. I'm a beginner with php so I think I need to change content.php in my theme in order to do step 2, but I don't know how. I can't even figure out how to paste the code from content.php and have it all show up here, so here's a screenshot of it. What do I replace? Thanks so much for the assist.

[image]

Comment: You'd be best to use the `the_permalink` filter to change the link. Do you want it to go to the attachment page, or to the image directly?

Comment: I would like it to open the attachment directly. In this case, the attachment is always a pdf.